# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Couchdb and docker

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, couchdb

- when use [ Axios or Fetch ]  to make operation on [couchdb]
- using localhost: request is pending
- and when test with postman the same problem

first solution is to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

- it works in postman but with the frontend request gives me CORS Error

My Envirnoment

- using coushDB in docker-composer.yml
- frontEnd is reactjs
- http library is Axios

```
version: '3'
services:
  couchserver:
    image: couchdb
    ports:
      - '5984:5984'
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=admin
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password
      # address binding 
      - COUCHDB_BIND_ADDRESS= 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata:/opt/couchdb/data
```

- Error Show is

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:5984/taskboard1' from origin 'http://localhost:5983' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

- Frontend code

```
// put request to create a new task
export const createTaskBoard = createAsyncThunk(
  'tasks/createTask',
  async (taskBoardBody: taskBoard) => {
    // using axios for put request
    const options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
    };
    console.log('here test');
    const { data, status } = await axios.put<taskBoard>(
      'http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:5984/taskboard1',
      taskBoardBody,
      options,
    );
    return data;
  },
);
```

Comment: @jub0bs Thanks you it's helpful,i solved the issue by modify the conf of couchdb local.ini, but after i read your link i think i will try it

Answer (score -1):

As i said it works in Postman , so i started thinking about how to make chrome like postman so i run chrome in this mode and it works well

```
google-chrome --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="~/tmp"
```

Another solution is to use chrome extension which solve the CORS issue